# Print occurrence / positions of words

Tags: r

I have tried some different packages in order to build a R program that will take as input a text file and produce a list of the words inside that file. Each word should have a vector with all the places that this word exist in the file.
As an example, if the text file has the string:

```
"this is a nice text with nice characters"
```

The output should be something like:

```
$this  
[1] 1

$is      
[1] 2

$a        
[1] 3

$nice    
[1] 4 7

$text  
[1] 5

$with  
[1] 6

$characters
[1] 8
```

I came across a useful post, http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Memory-usage-in-R-grows-considerably-while-calculating-word-frequencies-td4644053.html, but it does not include the positions of each words.
I found a similar function called "str_locate", however I want to count "words" and not "characters".

Any guidance of what packages / techniques to use on that, would be really appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with base R (which curiously produces exact your suggested output):

```
# data
x <- "this is a nice text with nice characters"
# split on whitespace
words <- strsplit(x, split = ' ')[[1]]
# find positions of every word
sapply(unique(words), function(x) which(x == words))

### result ###
$this
[1] 1

$is
[1] 2

$a
[1] 3

$nice
[1] 4 7

$text
[1] 5

$with
[1] 6

$characters
[1] 8
```

Comment: thank you very much! It works. I need to check on "sapply" documentation then for more info (didn't know that)